# Existence and uniquenness of a point attains the distance between a point and a nonconvex set?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Following is from *Functional Analysis* book by Conway :

[image]

Convexity of K is 'heavily' used in both proofs of existence and uniqueness of the point such that the infimum is attained. But even analyzing the proof for a long time still I couldn't come up with an example that either existence or uniqueness or both cannot be happened if we drop the convexity from the hypothesis of the statement. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Counterexamples to uniqueness are very easy--try a 1-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: For non-uniqueness think of a sphere in the plane, with $h$ being its center.  For non-existence, consider $K=(0,1)$, and $h=2$ in the real line.

Comment: You added a bounty to this question but Ruy already provided a complete answer (you could argue that $K$ in his second example is convex, but the existence has to do with closedness, nothing with convexity, so that is best example you will get). Could you indicate why you added the bounty?

Comment: @LinAlg, could you give me an example of a closed non convex set and explain why it violates the conclusion of the theorem?

Comment: @Ruy, I can't understand "a sphere in the plane" and how it is an example of a closed non convex set and why it violates the conclusion of the theorem?

Comment: The sphere is the boundary of the ball which, in two dimensions, is more commonly called a circle.

Comment: @Ruy, thanks, I understood for uniqueness; do you know of any set closed non-convex that violates existence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the question of non-uniqueness has already been settled in the comments.  So here is an example of a closed,
non-convex set, for  which existence fails.

Consider the  Hilbert space $\ell ^2$ with its standard orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$, and   for each $n$,  let
$$
  y_n=\frac{n+1}ne_n.
  $$
Defining
$$
  K=\{y_n: n\in  {\mathbb N}\},
  $$
observe that for distinct $n$ and $m$, one has that
$$
  \|y_n-y_m\| =
  \sqrt{\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^2 + \left(\frac{m+1}m\right)^2} \geq 
  \sqrt2.
  $$
We then see that $K$ contains no  converging sequence, except for the eventually constant ones, and
consequently it is  closed.  Setting $h = 0$, it is easy to see that
$
  \text{dist}(h,K)=1,
  $
but clearly there is no $k_0$ in $K$ realizing that distance.

Comment: Two questions: 1- Do you say K to be closed vacuously, i.e. "a set closed is when it contains all its limit points and because K has no limit points to consider to it is closed vacuously"? & 2- Do you say K to be convex by this argument: "for 0<a<1 and y_n and y_m, there is no p such that a y_n + (1-a) y_m = y_p"?

Comment: I suppose you mean "$K$ **not** to be convex", right?  If so then yes for both questions!

Comment: yes, a typo! Thanks :)